# How to avoid sequential processing in NLP?

Tags: nlp

The general approach in NLP is a chain of process looking like:

1. Tokenization
2. Morphological analysis
3. POS-tagging
4. Syntactic analysis, or Named Entity Recognition, or Noun-phrase chunking, etc.
5. Classification (or any "end goal" of the program)

I've always found strange that each step makes decisions without "consulting with" posterior steps. For instance, you might POS-tag a word as a noun, even if it makes any syntactic analysis impossible further down the processing.

I was wondering if there were some approaches to this general NLP problem which take into account posterior steps. A kind of belief propagation, if you will.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at "Pipeline Iteration" by Hollingshead and Roark (http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/P/P07/P07-1120.pdf), and Kristy Hollingshead's subsequent work on pipelines in general and communication between pipeline stages.

Answer (score 0):

The pipe you have described is generally how many applications are structured, but it is not the only possible architecture. Some approaches involve multiple passes through the pipeline, where information from one stage is used at the next. Other work combines some of the steps you have listed, such as morphological analysis and PoS tagging. I recently read a paper called "A Hierarchical Dirichlet Process Model for Joint POS and Morphology Induction" where the PoS tags and morphology are induced together because they are co-dependent.